# What kind of webservice can be called with just a browser url?

Tags: web-services, browser, client

Can a webservice be written in such a way that it can be called via just a browser url?

For eg. if the webservice is called GetStockQuote, then it should be callable by the following url on the browser

```
http://myserver.com/WebServices/GetStockQuote?sym=MSFT
```

Likewise, if there are more params, they can be passed via the URL.

Unlike this one - http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx - where it doesn't look like the param can be passed via a URL. It seems to require either a program or a human to type in the param & click on invoke.

Or does it always require a client program? Is there a way from the wsdl to figure out whether it can be called from a browser or not.

How can I program a webservice which fulfils the above criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course a web service can be called directly by the browser! It's called a RESTful web service. Any RESTful API that uses the GET method (as opposed to POST, which is what your example uses), can be navigated to by typing in the URL. Here's an example:

`http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui?name=lipitor`

This API, from the National Institutes of Health, gets a prescription identifier for a drug based off its name (here, "Lipitor").

In order to program a web service that acts in this way, you have to write a response to an HTTP GET request--however you want to approach that, in whatever language you want (if you provide more details, I'd be happy to help). The other thing about GET requests is that they are only supposed to retrieve data; they cannot have side effects of any kind. For those kinds of requests, you would need to use POST, DELETE, etc., which can't simply be typed into a browser.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you mean by side effects?

Comment: Is it possible to look at a wsdl and say if a web service is RESTful or not & whether it supports GET?

Comment: In other words, if I call that API method again, I should get back the same result no matter how many times I call it (disregarding what effect other API calls would have on it). So you shouldn't ever have a GET request that updates data, for instance. I'm not familiar with WSDL, but it seems to have binding data. If the service binds to HTTP GET, then you can use it in that fashion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wsdl, you're probably coding to a C# wrapper that abstracts away all of the HTTP responses into a standard SOAP envelope.  Which I hear works fairly well if everyone speaks the same variety of SOAP any you don't really want emergent cross-platform mashups incorporating your service.

Assuming that you're using the afore presumed C#, you can write a "RESTful" service simply by leveraging the classic ASP roots of ASP.NET and making a page that returns a body of XML or JSON.  Bonus points for including an option for either, and either using an established schema or providing a human-friendly XSL.

(And if you're not using ASP.NET, much the same practice can serve in PHP, Node, JSP or what have you.  And you can probably find a pure C# library to do the same if you really look.)